# Dropbox syncing isn't working automatically or lately on my Elementary OS 6 and 5.1

Tags: elementary-project, dropbox

I have installed Dropbox through the app store of elementary os in 5.1 Hera (Laptop) and 6.0 Odin (PC). **Dropbox syncing isn't working automatically or lately.**

I would like to have an icon of Dropbox in the Wingpanel and have it display the current status (updated, synchronizing, offline).

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help with the automatic syncing, you can have Dropbox launch at startup. After installing Dropbox from AppCenter (which installs it from the Flathub repository), go to System Settings > Applications > Startup, and then add Dropbox to this list.

Since launch at startup is not set by default, the Dropbox folders only sync when the Dropbox application is launched with the default settings.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works!